# VSCode cannot find module '@angular/core' or any other modules

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

My project was generated with Angular CLI version 1.2.6.

I can compile the project and it works fine, but I always get error in VSCode telling me:

> ```
> cannot  find module '@angular/core'
> cannot find module '@angular/router'
> cannot find module .....
> ```

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

I have attached  content of my `tsconfig.json` file
this has been  really frustrating for me, spending 2 hours to figure out what is wrong,
I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the VSCode
it doesn't work.

Here is my environment specification:

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.4
@angular/common: 4.3.4
@angular/compiler: 4.3.4
@angular/core: 4.3.4
@angular/forms: 4.3.4
@angular/http: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.4
@angular/router: 4.3.4
@angular/cli: 1.2.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.4
@angular/language-service: 4.3.4
```

OS: Microsoft vs 10 enterprise

project root folder

```
.angular-cli.json
.editorconfig
.gitignore
.vscode
e2e
karma.conf.js
node_modules
package.json
protractor.conf.js
README.md
src
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

`node_modules` folder

```
-@angular
--animations
--cli
--common
--compiler
--compiler-cli
--core
---@angular
---bundles
---core.d.ts
---core.metadata.json
---package.json
---public_api.d.ts
---README.md
---src
---testing
---testing.d.ts
---testing.metadata.json
--forms
--http
--language-service
--platform-browser
--platform-browser-dynamic
--router
--tsc-wrapped
@ng-bootstrap
@ngtools
-@types
--jasmine
--jasminewd2
--node
--q
--selenium-webdriver
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It's because you've installed angular core as global. Intellisense cannot find it in node_modules.

Comment: angular core is in my node_module

Comment: Did you open a project in `vscode` before you `npm install`? If `yes` have you try to restart `vscode` after that ?

Comment: i have restarted 100 times

Comment: Can you try to generate a new project using cli, `npm install` and then see if there is the same thing with that one?

Comment: for me, I had to reinstall angularfire2

Comment: LOL Thanks!  Restarting VSCode sorted it for me.  This was driving me mad!

Comment: Restarting VSCode worked for me as well. Why doesn't Intellisense kind of _reload_ after a `npm install` ? Sounds like a basic feature to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled all extension I had already installed, and it turns out JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense extension from below address caused the issue.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sourcegraph.javascript-typescript

the point here is when you visit the website you see there is a yellow label, telling you it is in preview release, but when you browse in vs extensions, you don't see that label.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still having this issue, even after uninstalling *all* extensions and restarting VS Code. :/

Comment: Apologies, I should have given an update on this. Yes, it seems to have cleared up, but I'm not sure I recall exactly how. However, some things I definitely did do: A) completely deleted and re-created my solution, B) uninstalled and re-installed Angular CLI, C) rebooted my machine. Hope this might help someone. If it happens again, I'll try to be more methodical about determining how I fix it, so that I can report back a repeatable solution.

Comment: Another possible solution is to click on the status bar and select "Use Workspace Version", see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34681

Answer (score 188):

I was facing this issue only while importing my own created components/services
For those of you like me, for whom the accepted solution did not work, can try this:

Add

```
"baseUrl": "src"
```

in your `tsconfig.json`. The reason is that visual code IDE is unable to resolve the base url so is unable to resolve path to imported components and gives error/warning.

Whereas angular compiler takes `src` as baseurl by default so it is able to compile.

**NOTE:**

You need to restart VS Code IDE to make this change come into effect.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in one of the comments, in some cases changing workspace version might also work. More details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34681#issuecomment-331306869

Comment: this worked for me...but now getting another error
Build: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'

Comment: @sam that does not seem to be related to this issue. Maybe post it as a new question alongwith your code.

Comment: This worked for me.  I added src to basUrl in the tsconfig.app.json file.
 "baseUrl": "src",

Comment: Adding "baseUrl":"src" in the tsconfig.json file worked for me.

Comment: Nice by Adding "baseUrl": "src" this in tsconfig and restart IDE resolve my issue.

Comment: So I'm here in 2019 and I'm still getting this error. I tried adding the baseURL above but this didn't help (did restart editor). I also tried to disable workspace > enable workspace after going to a TS file > right click version number > manage extension.

Comment: So I did this and the url was already there. So instead of doing it as explained above, I just restarted vs code and it fixed the issue.

Comment: note : to restart VScode Open the command palette ( Ctrl + Shift + P ) and execute the command: >Reload Window.

Comment: being a newbie looking for this answer, it may be useful to share that this needs to be added under the `"compilerOptions"` in the tsconfig.json as mentioned

Comment: I has something similar. I named my module `MyFile` and not `MyFile.ts`.

Answer (score 129):

Most likely missing `node_modules` package in the angular project, run:

```
npm install
```

inside the angular project folder.

Comment: The directory tree in the original question contained the node_moduls/@angular/core folder, but maybe it was empty.

Comment: then restart VSCode

Comment: Or, in my case (Windows file manager) MOVE the blame thing (node_modules folder) BACK to ClientApp where it belongs, where you had moved it from earlier.

Comment: @andreikashin Thank you! Just solved my issue ! VSCode needs to be restarted

Answer (score 65):

Visual Code restart is needed if any update or install or clear cache

Comment: VS Code updated without me knowing about it. Restart helped.

Answer (score 29):

the fix for me was to run

```
npm install
```

and then unload,then reload the project in visual studio.

Answer (score 19):

I was facing this issue in my `angular 5` application today. And the fix which helped me, was simple. I added `"moduleResolution": "node"` to the `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json` file. My complete `tsconfig.json` file content is below.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `moduleResolution` specify module resolution strategy. The value of this settings can be `node` or `classic`. You may read more about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

Comment: saved my career!

Comment: Best answer ever!

Comment: To the top with you!

Answer (score 11):

Delete Node Modules folder from project folder.Run below command

`npm cache clean --force`
`npm install`

It should work.

Comment: thanks, It works :)

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue , there could be two reasons for this-

1. Your `src` base folder might not been declared, to resolve this go to `tsconfig.json` and add the `baseUrl` as "`src`"

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

2. you might have problem in npm , To resolve this , open your command window and run-`npm install`

Answer (score 9):

In the VSCode status bar, it must be showing typescript version - like this

[image]

Clicking on that version number will show you this, different versions available.

[image]

If you are using the VSCode version then **switching to Workspace version solves the problem** if it is VScode issue rather than your `tsconfig.json` (I am already using that one, so not highlighted)

[image]

Comment: thank you man, I was loosing living motivations ...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by clearing npm cache which is at
**"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"**

Or you can simply run:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then close vscode, and then open your folder again.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install it manually.

```
$ npm i @angular/core -s
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem ,
As I'm trying to work on angular project in VS code.

The solution for which this issue resolved is .

1. Delete the node_modules folder if you have one in your project folder

2.run the following command in terminal

**npm install**

3. Then Run
   **npm audit fix**
4. Then Run
   **npm audit fix --force**

now the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Try using:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and then:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

instead of saving `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` globally.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, was strange because project compiled and ran without errors.
I updated npm and then reinstalled the packages

```
npm update
npm install
```

then vs code stop saying that.

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered this problem and fixed it by following commands.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i @angular/core -s
```

And then don't forget to restart your **VS code**. It must be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of stuff the guys informed here, without success. After, I just realized I was using the Deno Support for VSCode extension. I uninstalled it and a restart was required. After restart the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely npm package is missing. And sometimes npm install does not fix the problem.

I have faced the same and I have solved this issue by deleting the `node_modules` folder and then `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

This also happens when you are downloading/cloning the code from a source control like GIT. The node modules are not pushed to the source control using .gitignore file and you need to run npm install the first time you get the artifacts from the repo.

Answer (score 1):

this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sourcegraph.javascript-typescript was causing me the error in visual code, I uninstalled it and it works for me

Comment: "This extension is now unpublished from Marketplace. You can choose to uninstall it." as of 11 Nov 2019
mentioned on https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sourcegraph.javascript-typescript

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a mispelling of the import line. Check that you have spelt the `@angular/core` part properly if typing it out manually.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to import the entire project. For those who have this problem in 2019 please check if you have imported the entire project not a part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you did what I (foolishly) did... Which was *drag and drop a component folder into my project* then you'll probably be able to solve it by doing what I did to fix it.

**Explanation**: Basically, by some means Angualar CLI must tell InteliJ what `@angular` means. If you just plop the file in your project *without* using the Angular CLI i.e. `ng g componentName --module=app.module` then Angular CLI doesn't know to update this reference so IntelliJ has no idea what it is.

**Approach**: Trigger the Angular CLI to update references of `@angular`. I currently know only one way to do this...

**Implementation**: *Add a new component* at the same level as the component your having issues with. `ng g tempComponent --module=app.module`
This should force the Angular CLI to run and update these references in the project.
Now just *delete the tempComponent* you just created and don't forget to *remove any reference to it in app.module*.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when i upgrade vs project to angular 10, I had this errors.

Angular cli creates `tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.base.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` when i delete **tsconfig.json** and rename **tsconfig.base.json** to **tsconfig.ts** all things will Ok.
you must also change extends inside **tsconfig.app.json** to **tsconfig.json**

Answer (score 1):

I had same problems with Sublime Text.

I came up with following solution: I just edited

> tsconfig.json

in the root of Angular workspace to include my freshly created application.

```
 {
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./projects/client/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./projects/client/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./projects/vehicle-market/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./projects/vehicle-market/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./projects/mobile-de-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./projects/mobile-de-lib/tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that I ran 'npm install' in one of the projects and thought that was enough, but actually the solution/repo had 2 projects so I also needed to run 'npm install' in the other one too as they had separate package.json files. Reading the docs helped me to understand this;

> This command installs a package and any packages that it depends on.

> A package is a folder containing a program described by a package.json file.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in the right directory. if you are inside any pages directory the `npm i` command doesn't work. Go to the **base directory** to run the command

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is that you have to include `nodes_modules` folder in your project. You might face this problem when you clone any project from github through git command line.

Comment: probably not the case since when you run npm install on the root of your site in the folder that contains your package.json file, this folder is automatically created for you with the modules needed.

Comment: yah. if run nmp install then it will download necessary package by checking package.json file..

Comment: You should mention that they should run `npm install`. Otherwise, your answer doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Occurs when cloning or opening existing projects in Visual Studio Code.
In the integrated terminal run the command  `npm install`

Comment: This was already given multiple times. Anything new you'd like to add?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following two commands solves the problem for me:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng update --all --force
```

Comment: Posting multiple identical answers is, at best, ["highly frowned upon"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/504460) and your answers are liable to be deleted. In your case, you have also misspelled Angular in all of the answers.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

for Visual Studio -->

```
    Seems like you don't have `node_modules` directory in your project folder.
     
    Execute this command where `package.json` file is located:
    
     npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
npm i --save @angular/platform-server
```

Then reopen VS code

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of these solutions worked for me.

I'm using Ubuntu in WSL2.  It turns out VS Code needed to install the WSL extension to gain full access to folders in the WSL directory.  After that, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this error if your `@angular/cli` version does not match the version of the `@angular` packages being referenced in the project. For me, `@angular/core`  in my project was version 13.X.X but `@angular/cli` was version 16.X.X (because this is a new VM where I freshly installed Angular). I updated my project's packages to the latest versions, and the project successfully built. [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) is a useful tool for identifying what packages can/should be upgraded.

So my steps were:

- I had a fresh install of the latest version of Angular.
- Run `npm install -g npm-check-updates` to install the npm-check-updates tool
- Run `ncu --upgrade` to update my packages.json file w/ the latest package versions
- Run `npm install` (from within my project's base directory) to install the latest versions packages. Note - you can add the `-- force` flag if you don't care that the CLI is warning you about conflicts... this may be necessary when making big sweeping changes.

Another option would be to downgrade your version of @angular/cli to match the version of angular being referenced in your project.

Answer (score -1):

Do run

```
npm install
```

it will work most of the cases

Comment: This is incorrect. The questions states that it is compiling correctly and the the issue is with VSCode, not the compilation

Comment: My project was compiling correctly and running, and the issue was within VSCode, not the compilation, and npm install just fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem as follow:

1. Open Visual studio code with your project.
2. Terminal -> New Terminal.
3. Write `npm install`.

Comment: There are already at least 2 different answers saying "run `npm install`"

Answer (score -3):

From my point of view the CLI you are using and the libraries are mismatched. The ionic CLI version 1 cannot build libraries for ionic CLI version 4. The best solution is to try upgrade your CLI version. You can otherwise use nvm which allows you to run multiple node versions on the same O.S. This can help you use different ionic CLI versions across different projects depending on the requirements.

Check out nvm @: [Their official windows repo. There is also a MAC and Linux version.](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Answer (score -6):

If we get this type of error just use the command:

```
 npm i @anglar/core,
 npm i @angular/common,
 npm i @angular/http,
 npm i @angular/router
```

After installing this also showing error just remove few words then again add that word its working.

Comment: The original package.json had them already installed. What does “remove a few words” mean?