# Visual Studio Code can't resolve angular's tsconfig paths

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I'm trying to import some services using barrels and tsconfigs `paths` options but I can't get angular and vscode to get along.

If it works for one it doesn't for the other and viceversa...

My situation seems to be pretty simple:

- in `src/app/services` I have a service which is exported in a index.ts
- my `src/tsconfig.app.json` is just this:

---

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "services": ["app/services"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
}
```

and **my angular app compiles with no issues**, but vscode keep giving me errors every time I try to import my service from `'services'` giving me `[ts] Cannot find module 'services'.`

why?

I'm using typescript 3.1.6 and in vscode settings I have `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib"` (I also tried to leave the default setting, no changes)

---

**edit:**

if I specify `paths` in `./tsconfig.json` starting from `src`, vscode is happy but angular is not.

if I specify `paths` in both `tsconfig.json` and `src/tsconfig.app.json`, both vscode and angular are happy, but it seems a too stupid workaround to me...

Comment: And did you try setting the TSDK to your project instead of the NPM one ?

Comment: yep, no changes... also, I edited my question

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I figured it out, even if I'm keep thinking that is all absurd...

VsCode automatically looks for a `tsconfig.json` file and it doesn't care about `tsconfig.app.json`, so `paths` needs to be specified in `tsconfig.json`.

At the same time, the angular-cli scaffolding specify a `baseUrl` parameter in `tsconfig.app.json` which overrides the upper one.

**The solution is** to delete `baseUrl` parameter in the `tsconfig.app.json` **or** edit its value to `"../"`

(As a personal remark, given that vscode is largely used to build angular solutions, I think that there's something that should be revisited in the angular-cli scaffolding or in how vscode looks for tsconfig files)

Comment: I think it's also source of confusion for WebStorm

Comment: Glad i found this, it would have taken a while before i would have tried that (makes little sense)

Comment: holy crap, THIS is the answer :) I was getting depressed because it seemed like everyone had solved this problem just by locating paths in tsconfig.app or adding a glob at the end for directories..

Comment: Also changing the imports to "non-relative" in VS Code setting was a required to step to make this work for me

Comment: if I delete baseUrl or edit to "../"   it breaks when I start the app with "npm start"  what should I do now?

Comment: This also is strongly actual if you migrated Angular to NX monorepo. Thank you!

Answer (score 45):

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903511/vscode-cannot-find-module-angular-core-or-any-other-modules#answer-63870627) worked for me.

1. Open *Command Palette* and select `TypeScript: select TypeScript Version ...`
   [image]
2. Select to use *Workspace Version*
   [image]

Hope this answer solves problem of others facing the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

It seems VSCode **only** checks the `tsconfig.json` directly **in the folder your open**. It does not check folders above like tsc and does not look at `tsconfig.app.json`. So in some cases the `baseUrl` might be missing because VSCode simply has not read a `tsconfig.json`.

VSCode's limitation to a single `tsconfig.json` in a fixed place has been around for a while and it seems it's not so easy to make this more flexible:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12463 
(scroll to end)

As mentioned above this is annoying in Angular-CLI scaffolding with multiple sub-projects where there is only one `tsconfig.json` at the root of the workspace. Obviously the projects might have different `baseUrls` in their `tsconfig.app.json` which cannot all go in a single `tsconfig.json` at the root.

As a workaround I have in addition to the project specific `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.app.json` created an extra minimal `tsconfig.json` for VSCode in the src folder of a sub-project with `"baseUrl":"."` and open VSCode from there. I have not tested this severely but so far Angular compiling and VSCode intellisense both seem to be happy.

Comment: Examples please!

Answer (score 7):

I was struggling with this issue for a long time and have tried just about every solution on the internet. The project would compile but VSCode would not honor the "paths" declarations in my tsconfig.json.

What finally fixed it for me was removing the "include" and "exclude" sections of my tsconfig.json [image]

I'm not sure which one of the 2 was the problem, but removing both finally fixed my long-standing issue.

Comment: my tsconfig had been working for ages, but decided to go dumb with TS 4.6. i had to actually *add src* `include: [ "src/*", "some other paths" ]` to bring it back to life.

Comment: removing `include` fixed it for me

Comment: Seems totally random, but it worked for me on a non-angular project. I couldn't find any way to import from `/src` in mocha tests (`/test`) without using ugly relative imports. Also vscode intellisense wouldn't offer completions. I've spent a couple of hours poking around different solutions and finally found this. I giess "do less" is often a good answer!

Comment: Same happen to me, removing "exclude" section worked... don't see much sense on that BTW... I might be doing something wrong but I don't know what!

Answer (score 5):

In case you work with project Angular, let place `baseUrl` and `paths` in `tsconfig.json` instead of `tsconfig.app.json`.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Create `tsconfig.json` in your application near `tsconfig.app.json`.**
2. **Add next settings**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
       /* your_paths */
    }
  }
}
```

3. **In your `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` rewrite on `"extends": "./tsconfig.json"`**

---

**Final file structure**

```
projects
  your_application
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.spec.json
    tsconfig.app.json
tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible reason of issues with resolving aliases can be caused by using include property in main tsconfig file. Default value is `['**/*']` - just add '**/*' to the included paths when you override it.
This was my problem, but it was hard to detect that include is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue with the editor so go to tsconfig.editor.json and if you don't have tsconfig.editor.json then create one and there extend your tsconfig.app.json, and after that add "references" in your tsconfig.json and add the path of your tsconfig editor.

tsconfig.editor.json =>
[image]

tsconfig.json => [image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion and duplicate code for other developers you can create `tsconfig.json` then extend the other tsconfig in my example it was `tsconfig.lib.json` so my `tsconfig.json` to be

```
//!for vscode to detect other tsconfigs paths
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
}
```

Note: I had to exit Vscode ( `cmd+q` in mac ) and reopen it for this to take effect