# How to set up Angular app path to import components without prefix in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

I want to import components and services without any path prefix, like this:

```
import { CarService } from 'services/car.service';
```

From files in a Angular app structure that looks like this:

```
carproject
   src
      app (from here)
          components (from here)
             base (from here)
          pages (from here)
          services (from here)
```

Currently tscongif.json in carproject folder contains this base URL:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
```

And tscongif.app.json in src folder:

```
"baseUrl": "app"
```

Application actually allows to make imports in the format i provided on top of this question. The application starts properly.

But Visual Code does not seem to understand it. And shows error:

```
Cannot find module 'services/car.service'.ts(xxx)
```

How to properly configure baseUrls so i will be able to import components and services without path prefixes from places indicated above, and so that Visual  Studio Code will be able to find these imports also?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173852/1828900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your tsconfig.json. I'm assum that your services code in services folder so I will change the config

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
   "services/*": ["src/app/services/*"],
 },
```

Then you can import like this

```
import { CarService } from 'services/car.service';
```

Comment: As a addition you can then also provide a `index.ts` in that folder so that you can import everything from just like this `@services/index` or `@services`

Comment: @JohnnyDevNullThanks for comment. If i will use index.ts and import everything, does it mean i will not need to import stuff in each component and service?

Comment: @Tony Ngo I would need to define this for each folder right? Is there a solution to define it once and use it all along the road? And what should be inside tsconfig.app.json in the solution you have provided?

Comment: Yes. You could for 1 parent folder too like `"src/*":  ["src/app/*"]`

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski so did my answer help you ? If so please vote up and mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: @TonyNgo I can vote up, but this is not the final solution. Final solution is more from a comment of NileshMali (not entirely but from this the solution came)