# Cannot find module @angular/core & Experimental Decorators vs2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Hey after the last VS2019 update it looks like it started showing errors that aren't true.

For one, it shows that it cannot find angular core but it looks like it knows that the component and oninit are interfaces?

Also I've been having issues with experiental decorators triggering although that has been constant.

**There are no build errors... and publish and deployment work fine I just have error messages in VS** 
It is really annoying.

I've seen this post already and it did not include a solution to this problem: (yes i did npm install, yes I did delete package-lock and do it)
[vs code cannot find module '@angular/core' or any other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903511/vs-code-cannot-find-module-angular-core-or-any-other-modules)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help remove errors caused by: 
missing module @angular/core 
and 
Experimental decorators

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "OneSystem_MainSite",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run OneSystem_MainSite:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.13",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "7.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "2.23.0",
    "oidc-client": "1.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "primeflex": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "1.0.0",
    "primeng": "7.1.1",
    "quill": "1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25823#issuecomment-412344120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/typescript-error-in-visual-studio-cannot-find-module-problem-with-the-tsconfig-json-file/

the above link helped me a ton.

Comment: Check this out too https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25823#issuecomment-412344120