# Visual Studio 2019 typescript intellisense error TS2792 with import from '@angular/core'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, intellisense

In Visual Studio 2019, I am running an Angular 14 project. While I am able to compile everything just fine with the Angular CLI, within Visual Studio I am getting an intellisense error for basically everything in the node_modules folder. It's very annoying, and I have so far been unable to fix it. Any ideas what I can do?

Screenshot of error:
[image]

My tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You have included this "moduleResolution": "node" in your tsconfig.json and the "paths" looks fine. Did you try to rebuild your project restart vs and try again. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597926/cannot-find-module-angular-core-experimental-decorators-vs2019) can help you?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Yes, I have tried that. Strangely, the intellisense error goes away when VS is first restarted, but it always comes back again after a while.

Comment: Try to delete Node Modules folder and then run "npm cache clean --force"  and "npm install"

Comment: After rebooting my PC, all seems to be OK again. No idea why that fixed it.