# Cannot find any modules - Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, node-modules

I have woken up and opened VS Code today just like any other weekday, and to my surprise **ALL** of my imports now have errors.

Any import at the top of typescript pages all have red lines underneath with the error message: "Cannot find module 'module_name_here'. ts(2307)".

Even imports from @ionic/angular give errors. What has happened here and how do I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903511/vs-code-cannot-find-module-angular-core-or-any-other-modules?rq=1

Comment: I tried all answers solutions and still have the problem :(

Comment: a classic but worth a go: have you turned the computer off and on again? a new version of vscode came out a day or two ago so maybe that's got installed and something cached needs flushing?

Comment: Tried the classic tech support tip immediately after seeing the issue, unfortunately no help. I've just tried clearing cache that didn't work either :(

Comment: My node_modules folder seems normal, but my project must not have access to it or something as when I just tried to run 'ionic serve' I am greeted with: Looks like @angular/cli isn't installed in this project. - I have been working on this project for a good 3 months with everything working...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the node modules folder is corrupted, If the error still persists after you remove the folder, and run `npm install` , try and make a new project and import everything in there.

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue, thanks anyway for the suggestion